# Не сохранятся информация из input в базу данных

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных

Приходит сообщение проверки о том, что имя изменено, но в базе ничего не меняется

**Само поле ввода -**

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="name_edit" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" maxlength='15' placeholder="Your Name">
```

**Кнопка изменения имени -**

```
<button name="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
```

**Запись в базу данных -**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL'])) { 
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    die(); 
} 

include 'config.php'; 
$msg = ""; 

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$_SESSION['SESSION_EMAIL']}'"); 

if (!$query) { 
    die("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Something went wrong!</div>"); 
} 

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) { 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 

    echo 0; 
} 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']); 
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['id']); 
 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET name='{$name}' WHERE id='{$id}'"); 
 
    if ($query) { 
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'>Name updated successfully!</div>"; 
    } else { 
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Something went wrong!</div>"; 
    } 
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Помогите пожалуйста, в каком месте я облажался?

Comment: Всегда смотрите конечный SQL и пробуйте его исполнить в pma (например)

Comment: я исправил скрипт, у меня были ошибки в том, что я бессмысленно указывал id, неправильно прописал UPDATE - $query = "UPDATE users SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'"; , а также чуть обновил сам скрипт, убрав лишние функции.